Problem recovering image, local drive - VPS
I recently uploaded my API to a VPS, and I'm having trouble recovering the images that are being saved locally. Whenever I try to open the image URL, I get a 404 Not Found error.

I'm not saving the images inside the API root, but in another folder on the VPS system (ubuntu) -
Path: ROOT dir/www/ibcb_arq/uploads/posts

When I save them in the project root in the path > ./upload < everything works, but I don't want to leave them in the root because every time I need to do a BUILD, everything will be erased.





import type { HttpContextContract } from "@IOC:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
import Database from "@IOC:Adonis/Lucid/Database";
import Comentario from "App/Models/Comentario";
import Postagem from "App/Models/Postagem";
import User from "App/Models/User";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import Drive from "@IOC:Adonis/Core/Drive";
import { cuid } from "@IOC:Adonis/Core/Helpers";
import NotificationController from "./NotificationsController";

export default class PostagemsController {
public async postCreate({ response, request, auth }: HttpContextContract) {
try {
// Obtém o usuário autenticado
const userAuth = await auth.use("api").authenticate();
// Busca o usuário pelo ID
const user = await User.findByOrFail("id", userAuth.id);
if (!userAuth) {
return response.unauthorized({ message: "Usuário não autenticado." });
}

  const allowedRoles = [1, 2, 3];
  const hasAllowedRole = await Database.from("user_cargos")
    .where("user_id", userAuth.id)
    .whereIn("cargo_id", allowedRoles)
    .first();

  if (!hasAllowedRole) {
    return response.unauthorized({
      message: "Você não tem permissão para criar uma postagem.",
    });
  }
  const conteudo = request.input("conteudo");
  const imagem = request.file("imagem");

  if (!conteudo && !imagem) {
    return response.badRequest({
      message: "É necessário fornecer pelo menos conteúdo ou imagem.",
    });
  }

  let imageUrl: string | null = null;
  if (imagem) {
    // Salva a imagem no drive
    const fileName = `${cuid()}.${imagem.extname}`;
    await imagem.move("../ibcb_arq/uploads/postagens/", { name: fileName });
    imageUrl = await Drive.getUrl(`./uploads/postagens/${fileName}`);
  }

  const postData = await Postagem.create({
    user_id: user.id,
    conteudo: conteudo || null, // Pode ser nulo se não foi fornecido conteúdo
    imagem: imageUrl || null, // Pode ser nulo se não foi fornecida imagem
    data_expiracao: DateTime.now().plus({ days: 60 }), // Define a data de expiração para 60 dias a partir de agora
  });

  const notificationController = new NotificationController();
  await notificationController.sendNotificationToAllDevices(
    "Nova Postagem",
    "Uma nova postagem foi adicionada."
  );

  return response.created(postData);
} catch (error) {
  // Tratamento de erro
  if (error.code === "E_ROW_NOT_FOUND") {
    return response.notFound({ message: "Usuário não encontrado." });
  } else if (error.code === "E_VALIDATION_FAILURE") {
    return response.unprocessableEntity({
      message: "Dados de entrada inválidos.",
      errors: error.messages,
    });
  }

  return response.internalServerError({
    message: "Ocorreu um erro ao processar a solicitação.",
  });
}
}

config/drive.ts
import Env from "@IOC:Adonis/Core/Env";
import { driveConfig } from "@adonisjs/core/build/config";
import Application from "@IOC:Adonis/Core/Application";

export default driveConfig({

disk: Env.get("DRIVE_DISK"),

disks: {

local: {
  driver: "local",
  visibility: "public",

  root: Application.inProduction
    ? Application.makePath("../ibcb_arq")
    : Application.makePath("ibcb_arq"),

  serveFiles: true,

  basePath: "/ibcb_arq",
},

I've tried changing the paths several times but always without success
